# How to animate blur state in Cocoa macOS swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I made this code below which use a main file as well in macOS swift:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window: NSWindow = NSWindow()
    var blurView: NSVisualEffectView = NSVisualEffectView()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        window.styleMask = [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable]
        window.backingType = .buffered
        window.title = "Window"
        
        let backgroundView: NSView = NSView()
        backgroundView.wantsLayer = true
        
        blurView.wantsLayer = true
        blurView.blendingMode = .behindWindow
        blurView.material = .popover
        blurView.state = .active
        backgroundView.addSubview(blurView)
        
        blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blurView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        blurView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        blurView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        blurView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        let myButton1: NSButton = NSButton()
        myButton1.bezelStyle = .rounded
        backgroundView.addSubview(myButton1)
        myButton1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myButton1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerXAnchor, constant: -70).isActive = true
        myButton1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        myButton1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
        myButton1.title = "inactive"
        myButton1.action = #selector(myButton1Action)
        
        
        let myButton2: NSButton = NSButton()
        myButton2.bezelStyle = .rounded
        backgroundView.addSubview(myButton2)
        myButton2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myButton2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerXAnchor, constant: 70).isActive = true
        myButton2.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        myButton2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
        myButton2.title = "active"
        myButton2.action = #selector(myButton2Action)
        
        window.contentView = backgroundView
        
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        
    }
    
    @objc private func myButton1Action() {
        print("inactive!")
        
        blurView.animator().state = .inactive
    }
    
    @objc private func myButton2Action() {
        print("active!")
        
        blurView.animator().state = .active
        
    }
    
}
```

The code works but there is no animation happening, I also used 'animator()' there as well, but didn't help neither. I wonder how to solve this animation issue here?